# Write to an offset using DataOutputStream

Tags: java, offset, dataoutputstream

In my project, we are writing a file using `DataOutputStream`. We are writing different data types like short, byte, int and long and we are using respective methods in `DataOutputStream` like `writeShort()`, `writeByte()` etc.

Now, I want to edit one record in this file at a particular offset. I know the offset from which that record starts but I am not sure what is the right approach of writing to the file because only method in `DataOutputStream` supporting offset is the one which takes `byte[]`.

I want to write the whole record which is a combination of different data types as mentioned above.

Can someone please tell me what is the correct approach for this?

Comment: Are the records fixed size?

Comment: No, records have different size.

Comment: "only method in DataoutputStream supporting offset is the one which takes byte[]" => The offset in method [`DataOutputStream#write(byte[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-) means the offset in the _data_ you are writing, not some position in the _stream_.

Comment: Additionally: It's the nature of a stream to not provide _random access_ by  using offsets or similar. See Nicolas' answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you should use [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in order to **read** and/or **write** some content in a file at a given location thanks to its method [`seek(long pos)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek-long-).

**For example:**

```
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw")) {
    raf.seek(offset);
    // do something here
}
```

**NB:** The methods `writeShort()`, `writeByte()` etc. and their read counterparts are directly available from the class `RandomAccessFile` so using it alone is enough.

Comment: Of course if the records aren't fixed size, there's a chance of corrupting the file if you just overwrite content in the middle.